# Check if navbar got clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navbar and want to close it when clicking outside. The only thing I need to check is the click event of the body.

```js
var navBtnActive = true;

function toggleMenu(){
    navBtnActive = !navBtnActive;
    $("#navContent").slideToggle();
}

$('body').click(function() {
     // if( clicked target is NOT the menu ){ 
      // if(navBtnActive){ // just if the menu is open
         //  toggleMenu();
     // }
    // }
});
```

```css
#navContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#navContent button {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="navContainer">
        <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</button>
        <div id="navContent">
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Slider</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Calculator</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Imageupload</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Settings</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Search</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Servercall</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see below, my `$('body').click(function()` got the code for closing it. I just want to get a way checking if the clicked object is the menu itself or not. If not, close the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi you can try this code**

```js
var navBtnActive = true;

function toggleMenu(e) {
  navBtnActive = !navBtnActive;
  $("#navContent").slideToggle();
}


jQuery(document).on('click', function() {
  $("#navContent").slideUp();
});
jQuery('#navContainer').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#navContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#navContent button {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="navContainer">
  <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</button>
  <div id="navContent">
    <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Slider</button>
    <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Calculator</button>
    <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Imageupload</button>
    <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Settings</button>
    <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Search</button>
    <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Servercall</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just check the click targer [jQuery event targer](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

```
$('body').click(function(e){
  var $elem = $(e.target);
  if ($elem.attr('id') === 'my_nav_bar_id') {
    doSomething();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/ap7m4xnu/

```js
var navBtnActive = true;

$('#menuToggle').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    navBtnActive = !navBtnActive;
    $("#navContent").slideToggle();
})

$('body').not('#menuToggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#navContent").slideUp();
});
```

```css
#navContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#navContent button {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navContainer">
    <button id="menuToggle">Menu</button>
    <div id="navContent">
        <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Slider</button>
        <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Calculator</button>
        <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Imageupload</button>
        <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Settings</button>
        <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Search</button>
        <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Servercall</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `compareDocumentPosition` method. You can read its documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition

You can test if the clicked element is contained by the menu by doing the following:

```
var DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY = 16;
if ((navContainer.compareDocumentPosition(clickedElement) & DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY) !== 0) {
    // clicked element is inside the menu
} else {
    // clicked element is outside of the menu
}
```

In your example it would work like this:

```js
var navBtnActive = true;

function toggleMenu(){
    navBtnActive = !navBtnActive;
    $("#navContent").slideToggle();
}

$('body').click(function(event) {
    var DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY = 16,
        navContainer = document.getElementById('navContainer'),
        compareResult = navContainer.compareDocumentPosition(event.target) & DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY;
    if (compareResult === 0) {
      // clicked element is outside of the menu
      toggleMenu();
}
});
```

```css
#navContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#navContent button {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="navContainer">
        <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</button>
        <div id="navContent">
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Slider</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Calculator</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Imageupload</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Settings</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Search</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Servercall</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggleMenu(){   
    $("#navContent").slideToggle();
}

$('body').click(function(e) {  
    if(document.querySelector('body')== e.toElement && $("#navContent").is(':visible')){
     $("#navContent").slideToggle();
    }
});
```

```css
#navContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#navContent button {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="navContainer">
        <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</button>
        <div id="navContent">
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Slider</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Calculator</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Imageupload</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Settings</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Search</button>
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Servercall</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```